# mobile device browser width portrait and landscape

Tags: jquery, html, media-queries

I'm doing HTML5 responsive website for both desktop and mobile. What is the actual browser width (portrait and landscape), for example Samsung Galaxy S3 has 720px resolution, but i normally find that browsing in portrait showing much less than that. any pointer on this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into trouble with the viewport size.

Mobile browsers will have a virtual size for the page that is often more (and sometimes less) than the actual screen resolution.  This viewport scaling can be controlled with a meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This page has more details.  It's for iOS, but the concept is broadly applied:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: Thanks, and also i just found an interesting link. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml